# Plugin Name check unique or not

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am new in WordPress but I wanted to know how to check my plugin name is unique or not and how to upload this plugin in wordpress.org. Please guide me how is it possible. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple enough, check whether the name you are going to use for plugin already exists in [WordPress plugin repository](https://wordpress.org/plugins/). If not, then hurray... you can use the name and develop the plugin.

In case it exists, give your plugin a different name.

And to upload your WordPress plugin, please create an account and then follow the instructions

https://wordpress.org/plugins/developers/add/.

Comment: Ok, and how to approve a licence for that?

Comment: For uploading plugin to WordPress repo, you should be adding GPL license.

https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/the-basics/including-a-software-license/

Answer (score 0):

First, visit https://wordpress.org/plugins/yourpluginslug to see if your desired slug is in use by an existing plugin. If it exists and you don't want to change the name, a -2 will automatically be appended when you submit your plugin and it passes review.

Your plugin must be GPLv2 licenced or GPLv2 compatible and under 25mb when zipped.

Source: [Visit](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/276311/how-to-check-plugin-name-unique-or-not)